# php for plpgsql function

Tags: php, plpgsql

I have my plpgsql function (which is working really well

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION inscription (client.nom%type, client.prenom%type, client.adresse%type, client.cp%type, client.ville%type, client.pays%type) RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
DECLARE 
res client.code%type;

BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM client WHERE nom = $1 AND prenom = $2 AND adresse = $3) THEN
        RETURN 0;
ELSE INSERT INTO client VALUES(DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6) RETURNING code INTO res;
    RETURN res;
END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and my php code

```
$conn = new PDO("pgsql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

$select = "select inscription ('qq','pccccp','lldddl','76000','ROUEN','FRANCE');";

$stmt = $conn->query($select);
print_r($stmt->fetch()[0]);
```

My php page is always returning 0 AND insert values

Answer (score 0):

> My php page is always returning 0 AND insert values

The most likely reason is because you are making assumptions about the order of the attributes in the relation. Try changing your insert to use explicit columns.

```
   INSERT INTO CLIENT
   (UNKNOWNATTRIBUTE, nom, prenom, adresse, type, villee, pays)
   VALUES
   (DEFAULT, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)
```

Comment: I did this but still have the same strange behavior..
Printing '0' AND inserting into my data base